# SAXON - XPST0017: Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named

Tags: java, saxon

I have a simple jar test program which I use to parse xml with xquery file.
Problem is that in the xquery file I declare a java namespace :

```
declare namespace java="java:MyString";
```

Then for testing purpose I just have a static method toString(Object o).

When I execute it outside of Eclipse (who managed the classpath correctly when I set a class folder manually) I get the error in the title :

```
> C:\>java -jar XQueryJava.jar
> -xq XQuery\test.xq -xml XQuery\test.xml Error on line 9 of XQuery\test.xml:   XPST0017: Cannot find a matching 1-argument
> function named {java:MyString}toString() ; SystemID: XQuery\test.xml;
> Line#: 9; Column#: -1 net.sf.saxon.trans.StaticError: Cannot find a
> matching 1-argument function named {java:MyString}toString()
>         at net.sf.saxon.query.UnboundFunctionLibrary.bindUnboundFunctionCalls(UnboundFunctionLibrary.java:114)
>         at net.sf.saxon.query.StaticQueryContext.bindUnboundFunctionCalls(StaticQueryContext.java:1479)
>         at net.sf.saxon.query.QueryParser.makeXQueryExpression(QueryParser.java:106)
>         at net.sf.saxon.query.StaticQueryContext.compileQuery(StaticQueryContext.java:472)
>         at net.sf.saxon.query.StaticQueryContext.compileQuery(StaticQueryContext.java:502)
>         at xpath.AffichageXPath.execute(AffichageXPath.java:91)
>         at xpath.AffichageXPath.main(AffichageXPath.java:49)
```

I tried to use "-cp" and the folder I put the .class file in :

```
java --class-path XQuery\class -jar XQueryJava.jar -xq XQuery\test.xq -xml XQuery\test.xml
```

But still same issue.

If I put the class file in the same folder as the jar everything is fine.
Why is it not working with the CP argument ? I thought it was the point of it...

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the stack trace shows that you are invoking the processor with

```
net.sf.saxon.query.StaticQueryContext.compileQuery
```

which is a pretty low-level entry point, and there are many ways of getting things wrong at this level. I would recommend you use the s9api interface (`XQueryCompiler.compile()`).

One of the things you can easily get wrong is to run without Saxon-PE/EE enabled. Calls to reflexive extension functions require at least Saxon-PE, which also needs a license file to be present. Check that the Saxon Configuration is a ProfessionalConfiguration or an EnterpriseConfiguration.

Using the -TJ option on the command line, or the equivalent configuration property in the API (`FeatureKeys.TRACE_EXTERNAL_FUNCTIONS`) will give you better diagnostics as to why it is failing to find the function.

Finally, note that using `-jar` on the Java command line means that the class path is ignored: everything has to be loaded from the JAR file itself. This makes it quite difficult to pick up the license file and any external library classes, so it is best avoided.

Comment: God... You cannot load jar AND external class/jar ? :-|
So it is not possible to run a jar that load external classes dynamically like with xquery unless all classes are in the same folder as the jar...

Comment: The classes you need don't all have to be in the same folder, but they do all have to be on the class path.

Comment: Ok I eventually make it works I don't know exactly how...
I just did 10 times the same thing and it works now using this way :

`java -cp ".\*;classes\*" xpath.AffichageXPath -xq "XQuery\test.xq" -xml "XQuery\test.xml"`
I tried with a JAR and a CLASS in the classes folder and both are working with the main jar in the current folder.

I still does not see why they "forbid" using -jar and -cp...